# Rebind C-space in Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, cua

I've tried various version to no avail:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<space>") 'tempo-complete-tag)

(global-set-key [C-space] 'tempo-complete-tag)
```

I'm using CUA mode and running Emacs on Ubuntu, version: GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.0)
 of 2009-09-27 on crested, modified by Debian

When I run `tempo-complete-tag` manually it tells me it is bound to C-space but C-space still runs `cua-set-mark` (or if CUA is disable, `set-mark-command`).

How can I rebind the C-space shortcut in Emacs to a command I decide?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`C-h k (key)` will tell you how Emacs refers to a given key (which is "C-SPC" in this instance). `(global-set-key (kbd "C-SPC") 'tempo-complete-tag)` will do what you want.

I always use the `(kbd)` function for key-bindings, as it allows you to refer to the key the same way it is typically written everywhere else.

Do keep in mind that C-SPC is a standard `set-mark-command` binding! Personally I'd pick something different :)

Comment: Hooray! That did it! I was thinking of `backspace` and thought naively that space was called `space`. But we're dealing with Emacs here. :-)

Comment: Agreed; meta-space might be better than ctrol-space

Comment: To everyone using `evil-mode`: `v` is set-mark-command in `evil-mode` so go ahead and use C-SPC.

Answer (score 6):

Also keep in mind that "global-set-key" will only do what you want, if your mode doesn't override it.  I'm too lazy to load tempo to see if it does indeed override `C-SPC`, but it might well do so, in which case, you want to put this in your .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'tempo-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-SPC") 'tempo-complete-tag)
            ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative syntax for key binding is via vector:

```
(global-set-key [?\M-\ ] 'cycle-spacing)
(global-set-key [?\C-\ ] 'tempo-complete-tag)
```